# MATLAB's 'saveas' saves my figure as squares. But I want them to be more rectangular

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, save-as

I am using MATLABs 'saveas' to save off one of my figures as a .png or .jpg or whatever.

So I just do:

```
y = randn(1,00);
plot(y); grid on;
saveas(gcf,'y','png');
```

Now the problem is that the png or final picture comes out as a perfect square - even if I manually stretch the figure before I use the 'saveas' command.

How do I get it so save something more rectangular?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short sample taken from a [mathworks discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/53404)

```
figure('units','pix','pos',[100 100 200 400]) % create a 200x400 image
>> imagesc(rand(10,10)) % put some random data in it
>> print(gcf,'-dbitmap','test.bmp') % save to bmp
```

Using `print` like this saves an image in the desired resolution.

Comment: Thanks Junuxx, unfortunately not... in MATLAB when we plot something, we can stretch and squish the figure as we want, and aspect ration changes with us. But if I save it off it remains a square...

Comment: Hmm...well this has made a difference, only now it is capturing my entire screen!

Comment: Let me fiddle with it some more and Ill get back to you - thanks for your help btw! :-)